# How should I think about controllers resetting state with ng-view navigation?

Tags: angularjs

Given the simple app with ng-view at the bottom of this post ([jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/henrikn/4fhu4/3/)):

When I wait for 2 seconds "one: initial" changes to "one: changed". If I then click "Two" and then "One", the text is back to "one: initial".

That confused me – my mental model is of two "sub apps" in parallel with only one visible at the time.

I assume that's the wrong way to think about it, since One resets. How should I think instead?

And what's an Angular-y way to solve the fact that `OneCtrl` loses its `$scope` state when I switch away from and back to it? I could store the state on `$rootScope` – would that be good practice?

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <p><a href="#/one">One</a> | <a href="#/two">Two</a></p>
  <ng-view>Loading…</ng-view>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="one.html"><p>{{state}}</p></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="two.html"><p>two</p></script>
</div>
```

JS:

```
angular.module('app', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/one', {templateUrl: 'one.html',   controller: OneCtrl}).
      when('/two', {templateUrl: 'two.html',   controller: TwoCtrl}).
      otherwise({redirectTo: '/one'});
}]);

function OneCtrl($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.state = "one: initial";
  $timeout(function() { $scope.state = "one: changed" }, 2000);
}

function TwoCtrl($scope) {
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller is re-initialized every route change. If you want to persist changes to 'state' then you could save the state higher up scope chain in the scope of `parentCtrl` controller:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="parentCtrl" ng-init="state={ value:'one: initial'}">
  <p><a href="#/one">One</a> | <a href="#/two">Two</a></p>
  <ng-view>Loading…</ng-view>

  <script type="text/ng-template" id="one.html"><p>{{state}}</p></script>
  <script type="text/ng-template" id="two.html"><p>two</p></script>
</div>
```

Then in your route views, set the state which was inherited from the parent scope:

```
function OneCtrl($scope, $timeout) {

  $timeout(function() { $scope.state.value = "one: changed" }, 2000);
}

function TwoCtrl($scope) {
}
```

There is nothing wrong with doing it this way. But I think a better practice would be to store state in Services.  Since they are always Singletons and injectable, your controllers can easily share instance data and encapsulated functionality without having to worry routing causing issues.

Comment: Thank you. Well explained, and thanks for the code example. So I guess one way of thinking about it is that the controller should coordinate data between some model layer and the view, but it shouldn't be the place to persist that data.

Comment: Oh, I probably misused "persist" here. I meant persist in memory beyond controller changes.

Comment: Sorry it was likely my misunderstanding. I agree with you:)